# Specific design needed for an informative box

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a text box design that I need to develop. It is in Figma, and the design is as follows: [image]

At the moment I have developed the following:

```css
<style>.info-box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 16px;
}

.info-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.info-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.info-icon {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #2196f3;
}

.info-content {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.info-number-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

</style>
```

```html
<mat-card class="info-box">
  <mat-card-content>
    <div class="info-section">
      <span class="info-header mat-h2 mat-primary"><mat-icon
            class="info-icon mat-icon-rtl-mirror">info</mat-icon>Equipos</span>
      <div class="info-details">
        <div class="info-number-container">
          <span class="info-content info-number">1245</span>
          <span class="info-pendientes">pendientes para parametrizar</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="info-section">
      <span class="info-header mat-h2 mat-primary"><mat-icon
            class="info-icon mat-icon-rtl-mirror">info</mat-icon>Tarifas</span>
      <div class="info-details">
        <div class="info-number-container">
          <span class="info-content info-number">1242</span>
          <span class="info-pendientes">pendientes para parametrizar</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

As you can see, I haven't been able to achieve the expected result using Angular Material. How can I adapt this code so that it looks exactly like the design in Figma?

Comment: Hey Christian, Can you complete the code in a Stackblitz/Codesandbox demo which includes the Angular material library? I think it is not currently picking up the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it required to use mat-card? If not, this would be easier solution: [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-card-sample-k5vzvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-overview-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss).

In short, your template could be:

```
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards; let odd = odd;">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'div-wrapper-odd': odd, 'div-wrapper-even': !odd }">
      <div class="div-icon">
        <mat-icon class="info-icon">{{ card.icon }}</mat-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="div-content">
        <div class="div-content-top">
          <div class="div-content-top-inside">
            <span class="span-title">{{ card.title }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="div-content-top-inside">
            <span class="span-number">{{ card.number }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-content-bottom">
          <span>{{ card.text }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And you introduce your cards as array of objects:

```
cards: any = [
    {
      icon: 'info',
      title: 'Equipos',
      number: '1245',
      text: 'Pendientes por parametrizar',
    },
    {
      icon: 'info',
      title: 'Tarifas',
      number: '2451',
      text: 'Pendientes por parametrizar',
    },
  ];
```

(Or use your special card type if you have it, isntead of `any`).

Your css could be:

```
.info-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #883995;
}

.div-wrapper-odd {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #dfdfe0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  background-color: white;
}

.div-wrapper-even {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #dfdfe0;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  background-color: white;
}

.div-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.div-content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}

.div-content-top {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  height: 22px;
}

.div-content-top-inside {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.span-number {
  color: #883995;
}

.span-title {
  color: #035dab;
}

.div-content-bottom {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #035dab;
}
```

I've kept classes `div-wrapper-even` and `div-wrapper-odd` with details, instead of using another class that has the repeating styles, in case you need further differences between the 'cards'.

Of course, you might need to further stylize the elements - for being (more) responsive, for being positioned differently inside their container etc.